# not adding repository

Tags: repository

For example

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive
```

I tried to install the above app but failed. In the same manner, some other applicationsI tried to install by adding repository failed to install. 
Please help.
I am using xubuntu.

Comment: Coud you post the output of installing the repository?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The "above app", in that repo, isn't available for all supported releases. Newer Ubu8ntu releases must install `grive2` instead.

Comment: vipin@vipin-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
<edited>
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpfw4r5jp6/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpfw4r5jp6/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key 7E2426D0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.
gpg: /tmp/tmpfw4r5jp6/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key 7E2426D0: public key "Launchpad PPA for The Fan Club" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK
Then I did update.

Comment: vipin@vipin-HP-Notebook:~$ sudo apt-get install grive-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package grive-tools
vipin@vipin-HP-Notebook:~$

Comment: I dont know to edit the comment content. It looks ugly. Sorry.

Comment: After adding repository of any app , it gives me the same message. I have tried for 3 or 4 apps.

Comment: Upload the command and its result on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ then share with us the link here.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24714489/

Comment: That repository does not have a xenial distribution. The last version available is vivid.

Comment: @heynnema Could you say the command I should type to install grive or grive tools?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: grive and grive-tools look kind of old. Use them with caution.**

**Note: you might review grive2 at https://github.com/vitalif/grive2**

You cite two different PPA's.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive
```

Should work fine for grive. If you're getting errors there, please articulate what the error messages say.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thefanclub/grive-tools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```

To fix the grive-tools problem will require you to open the `Software & Updates` application, go to the "Other Software" tab, find the ppa for `thefanclub`, edit it, and change the Ubuntu version from Xenial to Vivid. **Note: I don't know if the process is very different in xubuntu**.

Then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grive-tools
```

Comment: I downloaded the package from the website. I then followed the instructions given in the webpage. I dont know to change Xenial to vivid.

Comment: I tell you in my answer how to change xenial to vivid. Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you gave me the link to grive2. i downloaded from the webpage and followed the instructions.  it would be nice of you to anser me how to change xenial to vivid. what are those giants, I have no idea.

Comment: I struggled a lot installing linux. I liked xubuntu a lot because it consumes less memory. many of my fav windows app worked fine in xubuntu using wine. but, installing an app is so difficult in linux. I must have much patience to research. last 2 weeks I am on xubuntu. My ggodness, after much pain, it is working fine.

Comment: Living in India is easier than installing an app in linux.

Comment: WINE is a waste of time. Much better to use Virtualbox and install a **real** copy of Windows there. Regarding changing xenial to vivid, I said it earlier... I tell you how to do that in the last part of my answer. Hum... maybe the `Software & Updates` application is called something different in xubuntu, I don't know for sure. You'll have to look in your System/Utilities/Tools menu to find something similar that stores your repositories. Maybe somebody else can help us here.